# Envio JSON por Ajax a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estoy tratando de enviar un JSON por Ajax para recibirlo en PHP pero ¡el **POST** va vacio!

En PHP solo tengo: **`var_dump($_POST);`**

Y me devuelve: **`array (size=0) empty`**

```js
function submitForm() {
  var params = {
    rolName: $("#txtRolName").val(),
    description: $("#txtDescription").val(),
    information: $("#txtInfo").val(),
  };

  var paramJson = JSON.stringify(params);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./views/modules/request.php",
    data: paramJson,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function () {},

    error: function () {
      alert("error fatal");
    },
  });
```

Comment: Buenas Israel, podrías añadir el código y no imágenes, para que sea más fácil ayudarte con el ejercicio.

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo html de donde estas obteniendo los valores que deseas enviar..

Comment: Los datos si se llenan @DiegoAvila pero despues del success o en el php no los recibe.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `JSON.stringify`?  Puedes pasar directamente `params`, porque Ajax trabaja con datos así tal cual. Prueba a ponerlo así: `data: params,` y en el `success` debes poner un parámetro que será la respuesta: `success: function (response) {`

Answer (score 0):

Saludos puedes intentar de la siguiente manera:

```
Nombre:
<input type="text" name="nombre" value="test" id="nombre"><br>

correo:
<input type="text" name="correo" value="test" id="correo"><br>

<button id="mi_boton">Submit Data</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

        $('#mi_boton').click(function(event) {
        
            //obtengo la data
            var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
            var correo = $('#correo').val();
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "recibe.php",
        data:{
          nombre:nombre,
                  correo:correo            
        },
        dataType:'json',
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error fatal');

        }
       });
        });

</script>
```

De dicha forma envias la data por AJAX hacia tu archivo php, bien ahora donde recibo:

```
<?PHP
$data = array("resultado_ok");

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Ahora el resultado:
[image: result]

espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

Añadiendo a lo que ya se ha comentado, si por alguna razón quieres enviar los datos como JSON solo tendrías que dar un nombre al parámetro que quieres recibir en el POST en PHP de la siguiente forma: `data: {'datos': JSON.stringify(paramJson)}`.

Cuando usas la variable POST observa es un diccionario que asocia claves a valores, si colocas el string de JSON directamente no sabe interpretar que es y como asociarlo con clave-valor y por tanto, lo descarta.